# Issue with jQuery UI Droppable. Greedy option not being honored when re-binding events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I seem  to be having an issue with Jquery UI draggable and droppable.

I'm trying to create header groups, where if the header is dragged the contents are dragged with it.

As you can see in https://jsfiddle.net/ah19odmf/2/, I would like to be able to drag items to either the inner-droppable or outer-droppable, and also have the whole inner-droppable be draggable by dragging the header div.

This seems to work fine on the first run, I am able to drag items and drop them in either the outer or inner droppable without issue.

However once the inner droppable has been moved by dragging the header div, when I re-bind droppable to the inner droppable, the greedy option is being ignored.

Once I have moved the header, when I try to drop an item on the inner droppable, it appends to this div, and to the parent div at the same time.

I am currently working around this in my code by removing the duplicated item, but this is less then ideal.

Has anyone seen an issue like this before? Is this a bug with jQuery UI, or am I messing up in my code somewhere?

Any help is vastly appreciated, thanks in advance for any replies.

HTML Code:

```
<div class='outer-droppable'>
 <div class='inner-droppable'>
    <div class='header'>
      Header
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    Item
  </div>
</div>

<div class='outer-droppable'>
  <div class='inner-droppable'>
    <div class='header'>
      Header
    </div>
    <div class='item'>
      Item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    Item
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
        $( ".header" ).draggable({
          appendTo: 'body',
          containment: 'window',
          scroll: false,
          helper: headerHelper
        });
        $( ".item" ).draggable({
          appendTo: 'body',
          containment: 'window',
          scroll: false,
          helper: itemHelper
        });
        $( ".outer-droppable" ).droppable({

          drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.helper.find('.header').length > 0) {
                ui.draggable.parent().remove();
                onHeaderDrop(ui.helper, $(this));
            }
            else
            {
                ui.draggable.remove();
                onItemDrop(ui.helper, $(this));
            }
          },
          greedy: true,
          accept: ".item, .header"
        });

        $( ".inner-droppable" ).droppable({greedy: true,
          accept: ".item",
          drop: function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.remove();
            onItemDrop(ui.helper, $(this));
          }
        });
});

function headerHelper(event) {
    return $(event.target).closest('.inner-droppable').clone().css("width", $(event.target).closest('.inner-droppable').width());
}

function itemHelper(event) {
    return $(event.target).clone().css("width", $(event.target).width());
}

function onHeaderDrop(item, target) {
    $(item)
  .clone()
  .removeAttr('style')
  .appendTo(target);
  var dropped = $(target).children().last();

  $(dropped).droppable({
            greedy: true,
            accept: ".item",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                onItemDrop(ui.helper, $(this));
            }
        });
    $(dropped).children('.header')
    .draggable({
            appendTo: 'body',
            containment: 'window',
            scroll: false,
            helper: headerHelper
        });

    $(dropped).children('.item')
    .draggable({
            appendTo: 'body',
            containment: 'window',
            scroll: false,
            helper: itemHelper
        });
}

function onItemDrop(item, target) {
    $(item)
  .clone()
  .removeAttr('style')
  .appendTo(target);

  var dropped = $(target).children().last();
  $(dropped) .draggable({
            appendTo: 'body',
            containment: 'window',
            scroll: false,
            helper: itemHelper
        });
}
```

(Really bad) CSS:

```
.outer-droppable {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.inner-droppable {
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header {
  background-color: orange;
}

.item {
  background-color: green;
}
```